# Drawing a cube with OpenGL ES using glDrawArrays

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0

Previously, I've been drawing some 3D shapes using glDrawElements, but when it came to coloring faces differently it turns out it's better to have unique vertices.

I've been trying to rewrite my previously working cube class to use glDrawArrays instead and providing colour (and normal but I'm not using it yet) data per vertex, but now I can't see anything on screen.

The flow is pretty much: compile shaders, create program and attach shaders, create buffers for model data, set program, pass pointers to model data, pass MVP matrix, draw.

I think I've done the equivalent things I was doing for glDrawElements, so I think I'll blame my shader code, but it's really not clear to me what's wrong. Any help appreciated.

```
public class Cube {

private final String vertexShaderCode =
        "uniform mat4 uMVPMatrix;" +
        "attribute vec4 aPosition;" +   
        "attribute vec4 aColor; \n" 
        + "attribute vec3 aNormal; \n"  
        + "varying vec4 v_Color; \n"    
        + "void main() {" +
        "  gl_Position = uMVPMatrix * vPosition;" +
        "}";

private final String fragmentShaderCode =
        "precision mediump float;" +
        "varying vec4 v_Color;" +
        "void main() {" +
        "  gl_FragColor = v_Color;" +
        "}";

// Store our data in float buffer.
private final FloatBuffer mCubePositions;
private final FloatBuffer mCubeColors;
private final FloatBuffer mCubeNormals;

// Bytes per float.
private final int mBytesPerFloat = 4;

/** Size of the position data in elements. */
private final int mPositionDataSize = 3;    
/** Size of the color data in elements. */
private final int mColorDataSize = 4;   
/** Size of the normal data in elements. */
private final int mNormalDataSize = 3;

private final int mProgram;
private int mPositionHandle;
private int mColorHandle;
private int mNormalHandle;
private int mMVPMatrixHandle;

final float[] cubePositionData =
    {...
    };

    final float[] cubeColorData =
    {...
    };

    final float[] cubeNormalData =
    {...
    };

/**
 * Sets up the drawing object data for use in an OpenGL ES context.
 */
public Cube() {
    // prepare shaders and OpenGL program
    int vertexShader = MyGLRenderer.loadShader(
            GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER,
            vertexShaderCode);
    int fragmentShader = MyGLRenderer.loadShader(
            GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER,
            fragmentShaderCode);

    mProgram = GLES20.glCreateProgram();             // create empty OpenGL Program
    GLES20.glAttachShader(mProgram, vertexShader);   // add the vertex shader to program
    GLES20.glAttachShader(mProgram, fragmentShader); // add the fragment shader to program
    GLES20.glLinkProgram(mProgram);                  // create OpenGL program executables

    // Initialize the buffers.
    mCubePositions = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(cubePositionData.length * mBytesPerFloat)
    .order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asFloatBuffer();    
    mCubePositions.put(cubePositionData);
    mCubePositions.position(0);

    mCubeColors = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(cubeColorData.length * mBytesPerFloat)
    .order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asFloatBuffer();    
    mCubeColors.put(cubeColorData);
    mCubeColors.position(0);

    mCubeNormals = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(cubeNormalData.length * mBytesPerFloat)
    .order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asFloatBuffer();    
    mCubeNormals.put(cubeNormalData);
    mCubeNormals.position(0);
}

public void draw(float[] mMVPMatrix) {
    // Add program to OpenGL environment
    GLES20.glUseProgram(mProgram);

    // get handle to vertex shader's vPosition member
    mPositionHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgram, "aPosition");

    // get handle to vertex shader's aColor member
    mColorHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgram, "aColor");

    mNormalHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgram, "aNormal"); 

    // get handle to shape's transformation matrix
    mMVPMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "uMVPMatrix");

    // Apply the projection and view transformation
    GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mMVPMatrixHandle, 1, false, mMVPMatrix, 0);

    // Pass in the position information
    mCubePositions.position(0);
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mPositionHandle, mPositionDataSize,
            GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, mCubePositions);
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);

    // Pass in the color information
    mCubeColors.position(0);
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mColorHandle, mColorDataSize,
            GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, mCubeColors);
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mColorHandle);

    // Pass in the normal information
    mCubeNormals.position(0);
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mNormalHandle, mNormalDataSize,
            GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, mCubeNormals);
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mNormalHandle);

    // Pass in the combined matrix.
    GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mMVPMatrixHandle, 1, false, mMVPMatrix, 0);

    // Draw the cube.
    GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 36);

    // Disable vertex array
    GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your vertex shader code misses to assign a value to the `v_Color` varying variable, which results in no color being passed from vertex shader to fragment shader. You need to add this to the `main()` function in the vertex shader code:

```
v_Color = aColor;
```

There's also a mismatch in names between the declaration of `aPosition`, and then using a (undefined) variable named `vPosition`.

I would strongly recommend that you check the results of your shader compilations, and study the errors when they fail. [`glGetShaderiv()`](https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glGetShaderiv.xml) and [`glGetShaderInfoLog()`](https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glGetShaderInfoLog.xml) are your friends.